# How to set state_selected for initially selected item in gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have a gallery with textviews. The initially selected item doesn't have state_selected. Even textview.setSelection(i) doesn't help. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your gallery (e.g. in onCreate) like below:

```
gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
gallery.setSelected(true);
gallery.setSelection(0);
```